# Issues with installing a library

Tags: linux, rhel, software-installation, tar, libraries

So I'm trying to download [vips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/supported/current/), and unpacked the tar.gz.

I then did `./configure` and `make && sudo make install`, and it ended with this output:

```
libtool: link: gcc -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -o .libs/vipsheader vipsheader.o -DG_DISABLE_ASSERT -DG_DISABLE_CHECKS -pthread -fopenmp -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread -pthread  ../libvips/.libs/libvips.so -lz -lMagickCore -lpng12 -ltiff -ljpeg -lxml2 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lfftw3 -llcms -lexif -lm -fopenmp -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/tools'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/po'
Making all in man
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/man'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/man'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/doc'
Making all in test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/test'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5'
```

But nothing was added to /usr/include and /usr/lib. Why is this?

EDIT: After running sudo make install, the output is

```
Making install in libvips
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips'
Making install in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips/include'
Making install in vips
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips/include/vips'
glib-mkenums --template enumtemplate \
        ../../../libvips/include/vips/resample.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/memory.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/create.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/foreign.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/arithmetic.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/conversion.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/util.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/image.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/colour.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/operation.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/convolution.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/morphology.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/draw.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/basic.h ../../../libvips/include/vips/object.h > xgen-geth && \
    ( cmp -s xgen-geth enumtypes.h || cp xgen-geth enumtypes.h ) && \
    rm -f xgen-geth 
/bin/sh: xgen-geth: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [enumtypes.h] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips/include/vips'
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips/include'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dir/vips-8.4.5/libvips'
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

so I guess there's an issue but I don't know why...

Output from configure is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fKR60Yob4_u2YcyUgr31M_SSdSV_7VXxs4-90O7ZZkI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps the default installation prefix is something other than `/usr` (for example `/usr/local`)?

Comment: @steeldriver, not there either :( trying to include vips/vip8 doesn't work, and that's why I'm confused.

Comment: Hmm...on reviewing the `make` output - perhaps `make` exited with non-zero exit code, so `sudo make install` wasn't executed at all?

Comment: @steeldriver you're right!!! updated, thanks!

Comment: Is `xgen-geth` a file? Can you list it? `ls -lah xgen-geth`.

Comment: Also, (broken record time), but why not just install a binary package for your distribution? This seems to be RHEL, but a Fedora package will probably work. You might have to rebuild the RPM.

Comment: @FaheemMitha no clue!!! It says `ls: cannot access xgen-geth: No such file or directory`. And I couldn't find an RPM for it :(

Comment: Run find on the build directory. E.g.: `find . -name 'xgen-geth'`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha it finds nothing :/

Comment: Check out https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/vips for example. Rebuilding an RPM might be a way to go.

Comment: What was the output of `configure`? Perhaps it noted errors? The fact that `make` did nothing would lead me to believe `configure` had issues.

Comment: @Deathgrip Wouldn't `configure` normally exit if there were errors?

Comment: @FaheemMitha - The build command wasn't `configure && make && sudo make install`. @user7554160 doesn't indicate how `configure` completed. Seeing the output of `make` noted that nothing was done, I wouldn't want to assume `configure` completed with no errors.

Comment: @Deathgrip Fair point. He could also check the configure logs.

Comment: @Deathgrip configure output added to question, thanks!

Comment: @FaheemMitha configure output added to question, thanks!

Comment: @user7554160 I don't see anything obviously wrong. But are you sure you got all of it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yup, that's all of it. I'll add all my make output to that same file though.

Answer (score 0):

`configure` always installs to `/usr/local` by default. I see:

```
$ ./configure
... output
$ make
... more output
$ sudo make install
... even more output
$ ls /usr/local/bin/vips
/usr/local/bin/vips
```

If you want to be able to run programs installed in `/usr/local` you may need to set `PATH` and possibly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, depending on your platform and how it has been configured.

To install somewhere else, use `--prefix`, for example:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/my_user_name/vips
$ make
$ make install
```

Now there's no need for any `sudo` and the package will be installed to a directory in your home area. Again, you'll need to set `PATH` and possibly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I would only build libvips from source if you really must have the latest version, or if you want to do development. There will be a version in your package manager which is probably good enough, and it's much easier.